# Button stays focused (hover) after clicked

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, vuejs2

I'm using bootstrap and vue 2.0.

It works normally when I don't click the button. It focus on `@mouseenter` and unfocus on `@mouseleave` like this.

[image]
[image]

But when I clicked button, it stay focused like this until I make another click anywhere, even in another window.

[image]

How can I fix this? Here is HTML and CSS code.

Button html:

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="search()"
                          type="button">{{$lang.ticketsSearch}}</button>
```

Button css:

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
      touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.btn:focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn.active:focus,
.btn.focus,
.btn:active.focus,
.btn.active.focus {
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:focus,
.btn.focus {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:active,
.btn.active {
  background-image: none;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
          box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}
.btn.disabled,
.btn[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  filter: alpha(opacity=65);
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
  opacity: .65;
}
a.btn.disabled,
fieldset[disabled] a.btn {
  pointer-events: none;
}        
.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  border-color: #2e6da4;
}
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #286090;
  border-color: #122b40;
}
.btn-primary:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #286090;
  border-color: #204d74;
}
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #286090;
  border-color: #204d74;
}
.btn-primary:active:hover,
.btn-primary.active:hover,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:active:focus,
.btn-primary.active:focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active.focus,
.btn-primary.active.focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary.focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #204d74;
  border-color: #122b40;
}
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  background-image: none;
}
.btn-primary.disabled:hover,
.btn-primary[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary.disabled:focus,
.btn-primary[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.disabled.focus,
.btn-primary[disabled].focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.focus {
  background-color: #337ab7;
  border-color: #2e6da4;
}
.btn-primary .badge {
  color: #337ab7;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: @Kondal I added the code. I guess it's bootstrap's defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When that button is clicked, it takes on the :focus state. If you don't want it to behave like that, you'd have to overwrite the focus state, but that's probably not a good idea. You could look into programmatically putting the focus on something else.

In this particular case to remove the "green" when you click and move away, you should only need to do:

```
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000; /*this is where the colour was green*/
  border-color: #122b40;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more explanatory? I'm a back-end developer and I literally have no idea what I'm doing. I just need to fix this.

Comment: I've added the code example of where I think it will fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you! Now it doesn't hovering if you don't click somewhere but I guess it is slightly less irritating bug. :D